# How to change makefile from making executable to make a shared library

Tags: c++, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have an opensource library that creates when I run the build script (.sh) an executable.

I need to include the library functions in another project so I want to make a .so file instead (I run it on Ubuntu).

Where in the makefile is this defined? And how would I have to adapt this in order to get the mylib.so file?

The Makefile:

```
    # ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects

bin_PROGRAMS = mybin 

MYLIB_SOURCES=\
    src/functions.cpp \

  MYLIB_SOURCES=$(MYLIB_SOURCES)

  MYLIB_CPPFLAGS = -Isrc/include -ggdb $(PTHREAD_CFLAGS)
  MYLIB_LIBS =  $(PTHREAD_LIBS) $(DLIB)

  MYLIB_SOURCES = progsrc/mybin/mybin.cpp 
  MYLIB_CPPFLAGS = $(MYBIN_CPPFLAGS)
  MYLIB_LDADD = $(MYBIN_LIBS) -lmybin

  lib_LTLIBRARIES = mybin.la
  libmybin_la_SOURCES = $(MYBIN_SOURCES)
  libmybin_la_CPPFLAGS = $(MYBIN_CPPFLAGS)
  libmybin_la_LIBADD = $(MYBIN_LIBS)
  libmybin_la_LDFLAGS = --no-undefined

# endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to give you a useful answer without seeing either the Makefile or the code.

Comment: I added the makefile code structure in the post. Where do I need to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just delete this line:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = mybin
```